# Powershell SMO - doesn't return User-Defined Table Type?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm trying to script out particular objects from a database using SMO (script cribbed from Phil Factor - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/).

Somewhat oddly, User Defined Table Types don't show up.

```
use YourDatabaseName
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[test_type] AS TABLE(
    id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
```

Now list out all objects within that database.  Note that the new Table Type doesn't show up.  Any ideas?

```
$Server = 'yourservername' 
$Database = 'YourDatabaseName'

# Load SMO assembly, and if we are running SQL 2008 DLLs load the SMOExtended and SQLWMIManagement libraries
$v = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')
if ((($v.FullName.Split(','))[1].Split('='))[1].Split('.')[0] -ne '9') {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended') | out-null
}
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum') | out-null
set-psdebug -strict # catch a few extra bugs
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"
$My='Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo'
$srv = new-object ("$My.Server") $Server # attach to the server

$scripter = new-object ("$My.Scripter") $srv # create the scripter
$scripter.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False
$scripter.Options.DriAll = $True
$scripter.Options.Bindings = $true
$scripter.Options.IncludeDatabaseRoleMemberships = $true

# first we get the bitmap of all the object types we want
$all =[long] [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseObjectTypes]::all
$srv.databases[$Database].EnumObjects([long]0x1FFFFFFF -band $all) |out-gridview
```

Comment: There's a bit of Rube Goldberg going on with the ANDing of the DatabaseObjecTypes enum. What happens if you just do something like `$all = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseObjectTypes]::all` and use that as the parameter to `EnumObjects`?

Comment: Ben. It was the first thing I tried. It gave SMO errors. I masked out thePlanGuide ( 40000000 ), 
DatabaseEncryptionKey ( 80000000 ), 
DatabaseAuditSpecification ( 100000000 ), 
FullTextStopList ( 200000000 ), 
SearchPropertyList ( 400000000 ), 
Sequence ( 800000000 ), 
Federation ( 1000000000 ), 
All ( 1fffffffff )  But I inadvertently masked out the UserDefinedTableTypes (20000000)  so pop that back in and you'll be laughing

Answer (score 0):

I've not done it the way you're suggesting before, but you could just have an array of objects that you manually load:

```
    $objectsToScript += $database.Tables
    $objectsToScript += $database.StoredProcedures | where{-not $_.IsEncrypted}
etc...

   $objectsToScript | %{
       $_.Script()
    }
```

Sorry, not at a computer with smo/posh on it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take an educated guess that user defined table types aren't included in the enumeration of [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseObjectTypes]::all.  The documentation on technet has no hypertext link for UserDefinedTableTypes.

You can get the correct info from [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Database] which implements the UserDefinedTableTypes property.  I've tried it and it works.
  The code probably won't be as neat as Phil Factor's since '::all' is a nicer way than getting the properties individually but it can be done.

Comment: I'll give that a shot!  Worst case, maybe I can just get the types he doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the .EnumObjects method requires you to provide a bitmap of all the different types of database object you want. If, like me, you decide that life is too short, you'll say 'All'

```
  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseObjectTypes]::all
```

SMO doesn't seem to think in a logical way. If the version of SQL Server you're accessing doesn't support all the database object types, it should shrug and ignore the fact. Oh no, it laboriously errors out, saying that the version of SQL Server doesn't support the types you've specified! To get around this, you have to OR the enums you want together to create a bitmap to pass to the method. Yeah, a lot of enums and I guessed it was a bit confusing in an article so I cheated and just masked out the ones I didn't want. Unfortunately, I must have masked out the user-defined table type. So in a production system you will need to go through the pain barrier by ORing together the enums of all the objects you want listed.

Nowadays, you can get the available enums via

```
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseObjectTypes].GetEnumValues()
```

but to be a bit more inclusive to earlier PowerShell versions, and get the actual value of the enums you can use

```
 [enum]::GetValues([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseObjectTypes]) |  ForEach-Object {"$_ ( $([Convert]::ToString($_.value__, 16)) ) "}
```

which gives you the values for each ENUM

```
ApplicationRole ( 1 ) 
ServiceBroker ( 2 ) 
Default ( 4 ) 
ExtendedStoredProcedure ( 8 ) 
FullTextCatalog ( 10 ) 
MessageType ( 20 ) 
PartitionFunction ( 40 ) 
PartitionScheme ( 80 ) 
DatabaseRole ( 100 ) 
RemoteServiceBinding ( 200 ) 
Rule ( 400 ) 
Schema ( 800 ) 
ServiceContract ( 1000 ) 
ServiceQueue ( 2000 ) 
ServiceRoute ( 4000 ) 
SqlAssembly ( 8000 ) 
StoredProcedure ( 10000 ) 
Synonym ( 20000 ) 
Table ( 40000 ) 
User ( 80000 ) 
UserDefinedAggregate ( 100000 ) 
UserDefinedDataType ( 200000 ) 
UserDefinedFunction ( 400000 ) 
UserDefinedType ( 800000 ) 
View ( 1000000 ) 
XmlSchemaCollection ( 2000000 ) 
SymmetricKey ( 4000000 ) 
Certificate ( 8000000 ) 
AsymmetricKey ( 10000000 ) 
UserDefinedTableTypes ( 20000000 ) 
PlanGuide ( 40000000 ) 
DatabaseEncryptionKey ( 80000000 ) 
DatabaseAuditSpecification ( 100000000 ) 
FullTextStopList ( 200000000 ) 
SearchPropertyList ( 400000000 ) 
Sequence ( 800000000 ) 
Federation ( 1000000000 ) 
All ( 1fffffffff )
```